# Jupyter Lab LuxWidget Lab Extension: RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

Tags: python, npm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I was trying to install luxwidget, a data visualization extension to jupyterlab but encountered this problem . I have different solutions based on the closest questions posted but did not manage to solve my problem.

you can find the complete log in the file attached
[log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ne4MM4wZ1q_9Q6HMOeqZsLi6cLWw5vjJ/view?usp=sharing)

```
warning vscode-languageclient@5.2.1: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @lumino/coreutils@1.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "crypto@1.0.1".
warning " > @jupyterlab/git@0.23.3" has unmet peer dependency "codemirror@^5.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/git > nbdime@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "codemirror@^5.0.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/application@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/apputils@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/cells@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codeeditor@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codemirror@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/completer@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/coreutils@~4.0.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docmanager@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docregistry@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/fileeditor@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/notebook@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/rendermime@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/services@5.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/statusbar@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/tooltip@2.2.0-alpha.0".
warning " > @kiteco/jupyterlab-kite@1.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "codemirror@*".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/application@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/apputils@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codeeditor@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codemirror@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/coreutils@~4.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docmanager@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docregistry@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/fileeditor@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/notebook@~2.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/observables@~3.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/services@~5.0.0".
warning "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "codemirror@*".
warning "luxwidget > bootstrap@4.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.16.1".
warning "luxwidget > react-vega@7.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.10.2".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Users\user\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\luxwidget: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: pip install . && jupyter nbextension install --sys-prefix --symlink --overwrite --py luxwidget && jupyter nbextension enable --sys-prefix --py luxwidget
Arguments: 
Directory: C:\Users\user\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\luxwidget
```

Comment: What is the Python version you are using?

Comment: I used  
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

import sys
print(sys.version)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
it shows 

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
@Carmoreno